# Case statement problem to show values without null in a row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

```
select  CASE WHEN ( rtt.us_code = 's' )
                  THEN rtt.name
                  ELSE '' END AS input_tax_name,
             CASE WHEN ( rtt2.us_code = 'r')
                  THEN rtt2.name
                  ELSE '' END AS output_tax_name,
             CASE WHEN ( rtt.us_code = 's' )
                  THEN rtt.acc_id
                  ELSE 0 END AS input_tax_rate,
             CASE WHEN ( rtt2.us_code = 'r')
                  THEN rtt2.acc_id
                  ELSE 0 END AS output_tax_rate
from supplier_item si
JOIN ret_tx_type  rtt
ON si.ret_tx_type_id = rtt.ret_tx_type_id
JOIN ret_tx_type  rtt2
ON si.ret_tx_type_id = rtt2.ret_tx_type_id
 where si.ret_tx_type_id is not null
```

I am trying to display input and output tax in the same row for a report depends on us_code is 'r' and 's'.
But i am getting the results like

if input tax is there ...output tax column will be null
if output tax is there ...input tax column will be null

i am want to get the both in same row and no need to make null in any rows

please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
  MAX(CASE rtt.us_code WHEN 's' THEN rtt.name END) AS input_tax_name,
  MAX(CASE rtt.us_code WHEN 'r' THEN rtt.name END) AS output_tax_name,
  MAX(CASE rtt.us_code WHEN 's' THEN rtt.acc_id END) AS input_tax_rate,
  MAX(CASE rtt.us_code WHEN 'r' THEN rtt.acc_id END) AS output_tax_rate
FROM supplier_item si
  INNER JOIN ret_tx_type rtt
    ON si.ret_tx_type_id = rtt.ret_tx_type_id
GROUP BY ??? /* here you should supply a column,
                presumably in 'si', that is common
                to both of the related 'r'- and
                's'-tax records */
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `GROUP BY` to your query on something (possibly `GROUP BY si.id`?)

And put the `CASE` statements into aggregates. e.g.

```
MAX(CASE WHEN ( rtt2.us_code = 'r')
                  THEN rtt2.acc_id
                  ELSE 0 END)
```